# How do I center a Label inside a Node in Godot?

Tags: c#, godot

I'm trying to center a label inside a custom drawing node in Godot. The label is attached to the node. The parent node is an hexagon, which (0,0) position is in the center of the hexagon (that means, there are negative coordinates in the node). When I add the label it seems to take the center of the hexagon as its top-left corner.

[image: Imgur]

However, I would like to have the center of the label in the center of the hexagon. That means, some parts of the label must have negative coordinates, but I can't find any solution to center the label the right way. Labels don't have size on Godot so I can't center it manually.

Code of Label:

```
var label = new Label();
tile.AddChild(label);
label.SetText("1");
label.SetScale(new Vector2(1.5f,1.5f));
label.SetAlign(Godot.Label.AlignEnum.Center);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the answer. If HexTile.Radio is the radius of the hexagon, centering the label consists of changing the margins and rect position:

```
var label = new Label();
tile.AddChild(label);
label.SetText("1");

label.SetAlign(Godot.Label.AlignEnum.Center);
label.SetValign(Godot.Label.VAlign.Center);
label.SetMargin(Margin.Left,-HexTile.Radio);
label.SetMargin(Margin.Top,-HexTile.Radio);
label.SetMargin(Margin.Right,HexTile.Radio);
label.SetMargin(Margin.Bottom,HexTile.Radio);
label.RectPosition = new Vector2(-HexTile.Radio,-HexTile.Radio);
```

Answer (score 2):

After setting align and valign to center, you can also set `rect_position` to half of `rect_size` (both are members of all Control nodes, such as a Label). In GDScript, it would look like this:

```
func _ready():
    var rect = $Label.rect_size
    var pos = -rect/2
    $Label.rect_position = pos
```

Be sure the anchors of Label node are set to 0 (or choose "Top Left" in Layout button). The position a centered text inside a label is affected by anchors, margins, position and size.

You can read more about it here: [Size and anchors](http://docs.godotengine.org/en/3.0/tutorials/gui/size_and_anchors.html)